# Can a Windows machine remain as active when I am connected to a VM that is running on it?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, vmware, sleep

I am using VMware(runs Ubuntu) inside a Windows machine. I am connecting into Ubuntu that runs under VMmare using `ssh` in order to do my work.

When I set sleep mode in Windows (Power & sleep => `When plugged in, turn off after ... minutes`), even I am connected into VM using ssh and working in it, Windows remains as inactive stage and sleeps on the given time duration.
*Please note that: Windows go to sleep even VMware is on and running a VM.*

Is the following possible? or could there be any alternative solution.

=> If I am connected into Ubuntu via ssh that runs under `WMware`, I want Windows to be in active stage, where sleep will not take place.

=> If I make the running VM sleep or shutdown, or even if I am not remotely connected using ssh, Windows could remain as inactive and go to sleep.

Comment: As long as there is user or application activity, Windows will not enter sleep. This means that the VM and you are both inactive. So you want sleep disabled when an ssh connection is open even if there is no activity, is that it?

Comment: If you somehow make the Windows Host machine sleep or suspend, then the Ubuntu guest will suspend as well. I have that setup here.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I want sleep disabled when an ssh connections is open (since I am the only one ssh into that machine).

Comment: @John I have the same setup on my end too. When I re-open the Windows Host machine, the Ubuntu remain from where it lefted.

Comment: Make sure the host is plugged in and set Hibernate and Suspend to Never. Allow the monitor to shut off

Comment: The only solution is to write a script that will turn off sleep, start ssh, and turn on sleep again when it terminates. This is possible if this looks like an acceptable solution to you.

Comment: A script that will run on the windows right? But behavior of Windows is not affected by the VM on my end.

Comment: What do you mean allow the monitor to shut off, on the Windows side right? Which I already did but had no effect @John

Comment: What I meant was to leave the machine running (so the VM remains running) so that (even when the machine is running) the monitor can turn off (if you are connecting from another machine)

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing but if the VM is remains running but if I am not ssh into it, Windows does not sleep no matter what; so I want it to sleep if I am not connected to VM @John